# Solving $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\log(1+\sin{x})-\log(1+x)}{x-\tan{x}}$ (doubts with Landau notation)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to solve the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\log(1+\sin{x})-\log(1+x)}{x-\tan{x}}$$

It is pretty straightforward by substituting those expressions by their Taylors polynomial:

Let $y:=\sin{x}$, then that limit is:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\log(1+\sin{x})-\log(1+x)}{x-\tan{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\log(1+y)-\log(1+x)}{x-\tan{x}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{[y+o(y)]-[x+o(x)]}{x-[x+\frac{-x^3}{3}+o(x^3)]}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{[[x-\frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^3)]+o(x)]-[x+o(x)]}{x-[x+\frac{-x^3}{3}+o(x^3)]}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{-x^3}{6}+o(x)+o(x^3)}{\frac{-x^3}{3}+o(x^3)}$$

Now, that seems to be $\frac{1}{2}$, and it is indeed, but I think I'm doing something wrong with how I manipulate Landau's notation, because I don't know how to simplify that to get the $\frac{1}{2}$. I'm having this same problem in several other limits, I'm not sure whether I'm using it properly or not, any help on this subject would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your result is correct but your method isn't perfect since you should write the taylor series at the order $3$. Let's show how to proceed for the numerator
$$\log(1+\sin x)-\log(1+x)=\log\left(1+x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^3)\right)-x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3)\\=\left(x-\frac{x^3}6\right)-\frac{\left(x-\frac{x^3}6\right)^2}{2}+\frac{\left(x-\frac{x^3}6\right)^3}{3}-x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3)\\=\left(x-\frac{x^3}6\right)-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-x+\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3)=-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^3)$$
and your work for the denominator is correct.

Comment: Thanks Sami, I think I have everything clearer now. I see that, when doing the logarithm polynomial, the $o(x^3)$ dissapears, thats one of the things I was always having trouble with. Is that always the case? Also, regarding to which degree you have to write the taylor expansion, in this case it was $3$ so it is the same as the denominator, or is there any other rule/tip?

Comment: I didn't understand your first question but to answer the second:  there's not a general rule to figure out the degree that the Taylor expansion has to reach but by practice we can guess this degree.

Comment: Oh thanks, regarding the first question, when you do the expansion of the first logarithm, you use $\left(x-\frac{x^3}{6}\right)$, and get rid of the $o(x^3)$. How is that? Is that always the case?

Comment: Ah I think now I understand the question. Look at the end of every line I already wrote $o(x^3)$ and it's not useful to write several $o(x^3)$ since
$$o(x^3)+o(x^3)=o(x^3)$$
did I answer your question?

Comment: Ah I see, thanks, I thought that including it would change the things since you would get $o(x^3)$ squared and cubed, but I guess that a $o(x^6)$ is also a $o(x^3)$. I have one last question, I promise! I see that, for example, $\frac{(x-\frac{x^3}{6})^2}{2}$ is reduced to $\frac{x^2}{2}$, even though it also technically has a $x^6$ term and a $x^4$ term in there when expanded. Is it because $x^6=o(x^3)$ and hence those terms are just absorbed into the final $o(x^3)$ as well?

Comment: Your questions are welcome. Yes that's correct!

Comment: Thank you a lot Sami, this has been truly helpful, now I feel much more confident in this subject.

Comment: You're welcome @LMartin.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Here is another simpler method of doing it using L'hopitals rule thrice.
enjoy!

Comment: Could this answer **at least** be the right way up before people start reading it please?

Comment: My neck just broke... anyway thanks for the alternative solution, I always like that, it's nice to see that L'Hôpital can also solve this.

Comment: @user88595 sorry!,but you could download it and rotate.

Comment: @IdeedRafiqi: I could... But clearly this is **your** answer, not mine.

Comment: @user88595 I said sorry, or what you are gonna hang me for this, huh.